# Google map disappears when reloading the layout

Tags: android

I've included a MapView in my layout and load the map during onCreate of the activity. This works fine.

Within the activity I load another layout at some point and then load the first layout containing the MapView again. At this point, the MapView visually disappears and just shows one giant blank - just blank, no gray grid.

I've included my map and MapView variables in the activity class:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private MapView mapView;
```

I set up the map during onCreate

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

mapView.getMapAsync(this);

mapView.onResume();
```

I'm populating the map

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    LatLng tee = new LatLng(49.784299, 8.529582);
    LatLng green = new LatLng(49.782525, 8.527233);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(tee, 17));
    mapView.onResume();

}
```

Comment: Where do you load another layout that makes it blank?

Comment: I've got a button on both layouts. There's an onclick event on both. Within each on click i load the respective layout. Both events are within the activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved. I need to call onCreate() on the MapView again. Essentially it'll look like this within my onClick event of the button in layout B:

```
    // set layout A
    setContentView(R.layout.content_track_shot);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    // for testing purposes I created a private savedInstanceState copy in the activity's onCreate method so I could use it on the button's onClick event.
    mapView.onCreate(test);
    // mapView is created now (displayed gray), now let's fill it with life again
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```